# Does the computer keep using electric while it is shutdown?

Tags: power, shutdown

Does the computer keep using electricity when it is shutdown?

I had a computer a long time ago that was very old, even without windows, it had only DOS. Then I bought new computer so I still had my old one but I did not plug it in.     After a year or so, I plugged my old computer in and turned it on, I saw that the computer had forgot everything that was on it!
The computer totally forgot every game and code we wrote on it.

I want to know, will it happen with every computer? Even the new computers today?

What parts of the computer are running with electricity even when the computer is shutdown?  Why doesn't my normal computer forget everything if I unplug it for a few moments?

Comment: what do you mean he forgot everything on him? what are those things?

Comment: It was really old computer with DOS. I had in it only 2D games. Like mario and stuff. But the computer totally forgot every game and code we wrote on it.

Comment: 1) Virtually all modern computers use some small amount of power all the time that they are plugged in.  2) No properly-functioning disk-based computer (especially the old ones) will "forget" what is stored on it after being without power for a period of time.  What you experienced was probably a disk failure or some other hardware malfunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the computer keep using electricity when it is shutdown?

Sometimes, but not in your case.  Let me expand a bit on that,

If you fully **power off** your computer then the computer no longer uses electricity.  <sup>*1</sup>.
If you put a modern computer in **sleep** or **standby** mode then it will keep drawing power, but less than when fully in use.

> I had a computer a long time ago that was very old, even without windows,
>   it had only DOS. Then I bought new computer so I still had my old one but
>   I did not plug it in.

OK, so it is old and has been unplugged a long time.

> After a year or so, I plugged my old computer in and turned it on, I saw that the
>   computer had forgot everything that was on it!

I think this is not what happened. The harddisk in the computer (the part which permanently stores your information) does not need electricity to keep the information. It can degrade (e.g. the oils used to lubricate the spinning platters can turn into a thick sticky paste, making the harddisk unuseable, but the information on the disk itself should lasts decades).

However you computer needs to know how to use that harddisk. These days that is done when you power on your computer. The computer powers on, runs it boot program from ROM (on PCs that is the BIOS or UEFI), and that program now probes which drives are present and how to access them.

On old computers (DOS era) this information was not probed but stored in a small static RAM **powered by a battery, even when the PC was turned off**. If that battery was exhausted then either replaced it, or you needed to enter some information everytimes you unplugged the PC.

And with information I mean things like:

- What is the date / time ?
- **Which harddisks are installed?**
- Which floppies are installed (e.g. 5.25 inch, modern 3.5 inch, none)
- Should I boot from the harddisk or from floppy.
- ...

This information is likely lost, but you can simply type it back in and use the computer.

> The computer totally forgot every game and code we wrote on it.

As I said, I think something else happened. Which is very likely if you also needed to set the time and date to correct values and if you need to do this every time you boot the old compyuter after unplugging it.

> So I want to know, will it happen with every computer? even the new computers today?

Modern computers still store permanent information from the BIOS and still use  battery for that.

> What parts of the computer are running with electricity even when the computer is shutdown?

The PSU will keep drawing a tiny bit of power as long as it is plugged in. In powered off mode none of this should be used by the motherboard.<sup>*2</sup>

> Why doesn't my normal computer forget everything if I unplug it for a few moments?

It will if you remove the on-board battery. But it will probably still boot with the default values after probing the hardware.

---

<sup>*1</sup> That is fully powered down and with the mechanical power switch in the 'off' position'. A modern computer comes with a PSU unit which usually draws about half a Watt of power, even when the whole computer is off. This is not just true for PSU in computers, but also for phone chargers and similar power bricks. All draw a tiny amount of power when not in use.

<sup>*2</sup> Minor exception to PCI era hardware which a NIC is kept partially powered on and always listens to the network. Which is needed to allow network boot.

Comment: Re. "This information is likely lost, but you can simply type it back in and use the computer." If the computer is really old, he'd have to know what disk drive is in it & the "parameters" (values that define the drive so it can be read) in order to enter that information;  some older computers of that era have a CMOS setup that will allow automatically determining the drive type, but it sounds like this isn't one.  It might even be easier to hook the drive to a newer system or put into an enclosure, to read what's on it.  @Hennes, your response was very comprehensive.

Answer (score -1):

computers have hardrives. This is basically the memory. This does not require any electric to store data. Someone must have formatted your harddrive or computers have bios battery like your watch has. If it was run out of power then you lose the settings. This is what i can tell you.

Comment: That answers his question, he should not have lost hard drive data/programs with the computer in the off-state or even unplugged.  To also answer the title: When a (modern) desktop computer is plugged in, and power supply is on, the system uses a small ammount of power that runs a 5v (standby) power. This small power is used to allow for wake-up from NIC and USB and PS2 devices or any other devices that can/will be used to wake-up the computer from the "off-state".